# Grails / Spring Security reuse a session?

Tags: session, grails, spring-security

I am facing a challenge when integrating a Grails application with a remote Payment Service Provider.

**Usecase**

After logging in, users are placing orders and when they are ready to pay, we redirect them towards a Payment Service Provider using hidden form variables. One of the form variables is a template URL so the service provider can render a page that fits our layout.

This template URL is now pointing to a controller action who's single purpose is to deliver the correct parameterized template.  In the template url we put some dynamic variables on which the controller decides how to feed the template. etc..

So far so good.. but now Spring Security ...

The problem is that the code in our GSP pages actually check if a user is logged in yes or no..

```
<sec:ifNotLoggedIn> ... </sec:ifNotLoggedIn>

<sec:ifLoggedIn> ... </sec:ifLoggedIn>
```

The remote system which fetches the template is offcourse not logged in, is there a way in which i can trick Grails to tell that the remote system can reuse a session from the current logged in user? Any hints on how to do this??

/Marco